# Push.on(‘notification’) not is getting triggered when the app is not open and not in background

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2, phonegap

I want to trigger push.on('notification') method when I click on the notification when the application is not running, not even in background. Is it possible? I am using phonegap-plugin-push.

Comment: Try removing and adding the plugin. Also, try removing and adding the platform.